# Issue with grouping a total count in SQL when there is a repeating column

Tags: sql

In the @exceptions temp table there is a field called CategoryId. I want @total to ignore any repeating CategoryId data...

```
set @total= (select count(*) from @exceptions);
```

If I group by @exceptions on categoryId i'll get more than one row back. I'm looking to get this on one line and keep it simple. Think like an outer select then the group by within but getting confused, any ideas?

Comment: Please specify dbms product? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use distinct count:

```
set @total= (select count(distinct CategoryId) from @exceptions);
```

This will return the number of *distinct* `CategoryId` values in `@exceptions` table variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `distinct` keyword inside aggregate functions like `count`:

```
set @total= (select count(distinct CategoryId) from @exceptions);
```